# Property undefined in typescript

Tags: angular

I have a problem in typescript that is the property of an object still give me undefined when I log it in the console.  Here is my class:

```
export class CustomerGroupModel {
    public Id: number;
    public Name: string; 
    public Active: boolean;
}
```

in `addcustomersGroup.component.ts`:

```
   public customersGroups : CustomerGroupModel[] = [];

   let customerGroup = this.customersGroups[form.value.customer_group];

   console.log(customerGroup);
   console.log(customerGroup.Name);
```

the output is

```
{id: 2, name: "Group2", active: false, customers: Array(0)}
undefined
```

Comment: Well, it simply means that what you're logging is not actually an instance of CustomerGroupModel. Also note the difference in the case of your properties: Active vs. active, id vs Id. Where does the data in the array come from?

Comment: it comes from service with type CustomerGroupModel

Comment: Post the code of the service.

Comment: public getCustomerGroups(){
        return this.http.get<CustomerGroupModel[]>(this.baseUrl + "api/CustomerGroup/getallgroup");
    }

Comment: this.customersService.getCustomerGroups().subscribe(data =>{
            this.customersGroups = data;
        },error =>{
            console.log(error);
        });

Comment: This should be part of your question, properly formatted as code. Not in a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you don't seem to understand is that TypeScript is purely a compiler. There is no type check at runtime. So, for example, this will run perfectly fine in TypeScript:

```
const foo: number = 1;
const bar: any = foo;
const baz: string = bar;
```

See: you end up with a variable `baz`, of type `string`, which actually references a number. Because at runtime, it becomes plain old JavaScript:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = foo;
var baz = bar;
```

So, when you write

```
public getCustomerGroups() { 
  return this.http.get<CustomerGroupModel[]>(this.baseUrl + "api/CustomerGroup/getallgroup"); 
}
```

you tell the TypeScript compiler: "trust me, the event emitted by the observable returned by `http.get()` is of type `CustomerGroupModel[]`". The compiler has no way to check that this makes sense, and there is no type check at runtime. Just as in the previous example.

But it does NOT make sense. All http is doing to transform the json string it receives into a JavaScript object is `return JSON.parse(string)`. That does not, and will never return a `CustomerGroupModel[]`. The only way of having an instance of `CustomerGroupModel` is to call `new CustomerGroupModel()`.

So

1. Make `CustomerGroupModel` an interface, not a class: it makes it clear that you will actually never have objects that are actual instances of the class `CustomerGroupModel`. Only objects that have the same attributes as the ones defined in the `CustomerGroupModel` interface.
2. Fix your interface definition so that its attributes actually match the attributes in the JSON sent by the server: `id`, `name`, `active`, `customers`. Not `Id`, `Name`, `Active`. The good thing is that it will also make you respect the TypeScript/JavaScript naming conventions.

Comment: What should I do if the backend returns the properties with uppercase? Do I have to remap them in every call? Or is there any easy form to convert them?

Comment: The interface should correctly describe what you actually receive from the backend. If you chose to not follow the JS naming conventions on the backend, then make the same choice on the frontend. Or fix both.