# Map like object in Vue and typesafety

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

I try to create dynamic object with properties in Vue component with keys and values, but the the only way I managed to do that is to create `const userProperties: any = {}` then return it in data(). The problem appears when I try to build in two places I had to add `//@ts-ignore` because compiler complains about:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Function': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Function'.

Full code I have so far for component:

```
<script lang="ts">

import {usePropertiesDefinitionsStore} from "@/stores/properties-definitions";
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";
import ax from "@/axios/axios"
import { toRaw } from 'vue';

export default {
  props: ['userId'],
  data() {
    const userProperties: any = {}

    const propertiesDefinitionsStore = usePropertiesDefinitionsStore()

    propertiesDefinitionsStore.fetchPropertiesDefinitionsList('User')
    const { propertiesDefinitionsList } = storeToRefs(propertiesDefinitionsStore)

    ax.get(`/api/properties?id=` + this.userId).then(json => {
      //@ts-ignore
      this.userProperties = {}
      if (json.data.results) {
        json.data.results.forEach((result: any) => {
          //@ts-ignore
          this.userProperties[result.key] = result.value;
        })
      }
    })

    return { propertiesDefinitionsList, userProperties }
  },
  methods: {
    saveProperties() {
      const dataRaw = toRaw(this.userProperties)
      const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dataRaw)
      const data: any = []
      keys.forEach(key => {
        data.push({
          'type': 'User',
          'key': key,
          'value': dataRaw[key]
        })
      })

      ax.post(`/api/properties?id=` + this.userId, data).then(json => {
        console.log(json)
      })
    },
    onlyActive(propertiesDefinitionsList: any) {
      return propertiesDefinitionsList.filter((i: any) => i.active)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there a better way to do that?

I tried to set dynamic structure on object without actually creating type, so my object is similar to Java's Map but created as Javascript object (keys and values).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Map`? and since you're using typescript (and typing is the point), why not create a class or interface for your user properties? if you do use a class, don't forget to call the constructor (or [just use an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049872/7898566))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).